# PHP $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] vs. Javascript document.referrer?

Tags: javascript, php, url, referrer, referer

Ultimately I need to know what domain is hosting one of my javascript files.  I have have read and experienced first hand that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` unreliable.  One of the first 3 browser/computer combos I tested didn't send the `HTTP_REFERER`, and I know that it can be spoofed.  I implemented a different solution using two javascript methods.

```
document.referrer
```

AND

```
window.location.href
```

I use the former to get the url of the window where someone clicked on one of my links.  I use the former to see which domain my javascript file is included in.  I have tested it a little so far and it is grabbing the urls from the browser very well with no hiccups.  My question is, are the two javascript methods reliable?  Will they return the url from the browser everytime or are there caveats like using the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` that I haven't run into yet?

Comment: `document.referrer` uses the same information from the client as `HTTP_REFERER`, so they can both be spoofed the same way.

Comment: Neither of these will show where the Javascript file is. `window.location.href` is the URL of the web page using the JS file. `document.referrer` is the page that contained the link they followed to get there.

Comment: I am not worried about it being spoofed as much as just not having it available.  Also, I thought the HTTP_REFERER was passed as an http header?  Doesn't window.location.href just grab directly from the url bar?

Comment: Yes, `window.location.href` is whatever is in the URL bar.

Comment: @Barmar | Sorry maybe i wasn't being clear.  I know the javascript file is coming from my server.  I want to see who is including it on their site.

Comment: It's possible that they can modify the behavior of these methods on the client before they load your script. In general, you can't ever be sure of something that's done on the client.

Answer (score 1):

You should always assume that any information about the referrer URI is going to be unavailable (or perhaps even unreliable), due to browsers or users wanting to conceal this information because of privacy issues.

In general, you won't have the referrer information when linking from an HTTPS to an HTTP domain. Check this question for more info on this:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47405/how-can-i-pass-referrer-header-from-my-https-domain-to-http-domains

About using `window.location.href`, I'd say it's reliable in practice, but only because it's interesting that the client will supply the correct information so that applications depending on that will behave as expected.

Just keep in mind that this is still the client side sending you some information, so it'll always be up to the browser to send you something that is correct. You can't have control over that, just trust that it's going to work according to what is specified in the standard. The client might still decide to conceal it or fake it for any reason.

For example it might be possible that in some situations, like third party included scripts (also privacy reasons), the browser might opt to just leave it blank.

Comment: Can the browser actually leave window.location.href blank?  If so, do you have any practical examples of how it is done or browsers that blank it out?

Comment: It's possible that some browsers (or plugins and extensions) could do that, however I don't believe this happens in practice, I haven't checked though. I'd just consider this information reliable.

Comment: I just want to point out that you can never be sure that the browser won't "mess up". It's still information that comes from the client side after all and it's good to be aware of that.